# How do I load an ErrorMessage on a CustomValidator from a resource file?

Tags: c#, asp.net, globalization

I would like to load the `ErrorMessage` for my `CustomValidator` from a resource file.

I have my `CustomValidator` set up like so:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="cv1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txt1" 
        ErrorMessage="TEXT TO BE LOCALIZED" OnServerValidate="cv1_Validate" />
```

And my validation method is as follows:

```
protected void cv1_Validate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    if (FalseCondition)
    {
        e.IsValid = false;
    }
    else
    {
        e.IsValid = true;
    }
}
```

The validation works correctly, but I would like to have the `ErrorMessage` be pulled from my local resources file.

**EDIT**: I'm also curious if there is any way to do this using `meta:resourcekey`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you have a local resource for your page (or control), this would be the way to do it

```
ErrorMessage="<%$ resources:ResourceName %>"
```

In case you get the text from a global resource file you should do something like this

```
ErrorMessage="<%$ resources:Strings, ResourceName %>"
```

Where `Strings` is the name of the file. This approach is called explicit localization.

**EDIT**

You can use `meta:resourcekey`. This is called implicit localization. You'll need to have local resources since this approach is not valid for global resources.

> 1. Make sure that you have local resource files (.resx files) that meet the following criteria:
>
>    - They are in an App_LocalResources folder.
>    - The base name matches the page name.
>
>    For example, if you are working with the page named Default.aspx, the resource files are named Default.aspx.resx (for the default resources), Default.aspx.es.resx, Default.aspx.es-mx.resx, and so on.
>
>    - The resources in the file use the naming convention resourcekey."property".
>
>    For example, key name Button1."Text".
> 2. In the control markup, add an implicit localization attribute.
>
>    For example:
>
>    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="DefaultText" 
>           meta:resourcekey="Button1" />

Source: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228093(v=vs.80).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in the code-behind, you can use the following:

```
ResourceManager resmgr = new ResourceManager("YourApplication.YourBaseResourceFile ", 
                              Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

protected void cv1_Validate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs e) 
{   

if (FalseCondition)  
   {  
       CultureInfo ci = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture;    
       String str = resmgr.GetString("Error Msg Key in Resource File");
       cv1.ErrorMessage =str;      
       e.IsValid = false; 
    }     
else   
  {   
     e.IsValid = true;  
   } 
}
```